# To find sum and percentage from columns of two different dataframe and append result in third dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have made 2 identical looking dataframe which looks like below:

```
df1:

date          id       email              Count
4/22/2019       1     abc@xyz.com           10
4/22/2019       1     def@xyz.com           4
4/23/2019       1     abc@xyz.com           5
4/23/2019       1     def@xyz.com           10


df2:

date          id    Email_ID           Count
4/22/2019       1   fgh@xyz.com         5
4/22/2019       1   ijk@xyz.com         6
4/23/2019       1   fgh@xyz.com         7
4/23/2019       1   ijk@xyz.com         8
```

I want to make a dataframe3 which has sum and percentage of 'Count' column of each dataframe(df1 and df2) and calculate individual percentage[`like df1_count%=(df1_count/df1_count+df2_count)*100`] according to the date. Output df3 should be something like this below:

```
df3:
                   Count                     Count%
date        df1_count   df2_count    df1_count%     df2_count%
 4/22/2019    14            11          56%            44%
 4/23/2019    15            15          50%            50%
```

How can it be done by pandas? I am able to do it using 'for' loop but not able to do by pandas functionality, any leads will help

---

Output as per solution @jezrael

```
          Count       Count         count%         count%
         df1_count   df2_count    df1_count%     df2_count%
Date
4/22/2019     14            11          56%            44%
```

4/23/2019      15            15          50%            50%

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: @jezrael its working thanks a ton. Can I make make df1_count and df2_count as the subcolumn under main column 'Count' and df1_count% and df_count% as sub column under main column 'Count%' in the final output?

Comment: Can you changed expected output in question?

Comment: Or need `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True).swaplevel()` before `df = df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have made the changes in output format

Comment: @jezrael The main column is reflecting above the every sub-columns. I have updated the output hot it is coming in my question. Also the 'date' column has been pushed one row back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192265/discussion-between-jezrael-and-sachin-kumar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregation `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.groupby('date')['Count'].sum(),
                df2.groupby('date')['Count'].sum()], axis=1, keys=('df1_count','df2_count'))
```

And then add new columns:

```
s = (df['df1_count'] + df['df2_count'])
df['df1_count%'] = df['df1_count'] / s * 100
df['df2_count%'] = df['df2_count'] / s * 100
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
        date  df1_count  df2_count  df1_count%  df2_count%
0  4/22/2019         14         11        56.0        44.0
1  4/23/2019         15         15        50.0        50.0
```

If need percentages to values first convert to `strings` with [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) for truncate decimals:

```
s = (df['df1_count'] + df['df2_count'])
df['df1_count%'] = (df['df1_count'] / s * 100).round().astype(str) + '%'
df['df2_count%'] = (df['df2_count'] / s * 100).round().astype(str) + '%'
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
        date  df1_count  df2_count df1_count% df2_count%
0  4/22/2019         14         11      56.0%      44.0%
1  4/23/2019         15         15      50.0%      50.0%
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.groupby('date')['Count'].sum(),
                df2.groupby('date')['Count'].sum()], axis=1, 
                keys=('Count_df1_count','Count_df2_count'))

s = (df['Count_df1_count'] + df['Count_df2_count'])
df['Count%_df1_count%'] = (df['Count_df1_count'] / s * 100).round().astype(str) + '%'
df['Count%_df2_count%'] = (df['Count_df2_count'] / s * 100).round().astype(str) + '%'
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True, n=1)
print (df)

              Count               Count%           
          df1_count df2_count df1_count% df2_count%
date                                               
4/22/2019        14        11      56.0%      44.0%
4/23/2019        15        15      50.0%      50.0%
```